# How can I post a list then access it in my controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I created a list property in my model like so

```
public virtual List<String> listOfDays { get; set; }
```

then I converted and stored it in the list like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30 i++)
{
            var enrollment = new Enrollment();
            enrollment.StudentID = id;
            enrollment.listOfDays = searchString.ToList(); 
            db.Enrollments.Add(enrollment);
            db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I put a breakpoint here... `enrollment.listOfDays = searchString.ToList();` ... and all is well.       I see that the conversion was performed and I can see the values in listOfDays.

So I thought I would find a column in my database called listOfDays since I'm doing code first but the property is not there.

Then I thought I'd try accessing it anyway like this...

```
var classdays = from e in db.Enrollments where e.StudentID == id select e.listOfDays;

var days = classdays.ToList(); 
//here I get an error message about this not being supported in Linq.
```

Questions:

- Why do you think the property was not in the database?
- How can I post this array to my model then access it in a controller?

Thanks for any help.

Thanks to Decker: http://forums.asp.net/members/Decker%20Dong%20-%20MSFT.aspx

Here’s how it works:

Using form collection here…

In  [HttpPost]…

private void Update (FormCollection formCollection, int id)

for (int sc = 0; sc < theSelectedCourses.Count(); sc++)
            {
  var enrollment = new Enrollment();
                enrollment.CourseID = Convert.ToInt32(theSelectedCourses[sc]);
                enrollment.StudentID = id;
   enrollment.listOfDays = formCollection["searchString"] ;//bind this as a string instead of a list or array.

Then in  [HttpGet]…

private void PopulateAssignedenrolledData(Student student, int id)
        {

var dayList = from e in db.Enrollments where e.StudentID == id select e;

var days = dayList.ToList();
            if (days.Count > 0)
            {
                string dl = days.FirstOrDefault().listOfDays;
                string[] listofdays = dl.Split(',');
                ViewBag.classDay = listofdays.ToList();
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Decker:  http://forums.asp.net/members/Decker%20Dong%20-%20MSFT.aspx

Here’s how it works:

Using form collection here…

In  [HttpPost]…

private void Update (FormCollection formCollection, int id)

for (int sc = 0; sc < theSelectedCourses.Count(); sc++)
            {
  var enrollment = new Enrollment();
                enrollment.CourseID = Convert.ToInt32(theSelectedCourses[sc]);
                enrollment.StudentID = id;
   enrollment.listOfDays = formCollection["searchString"] ;//bind this as a string instead of a list or array.

Then in  [HttpGet]…

private void PopulateAssignedenrolledData(Student student, int id)
        {

var dayList = from e in db.Enrollments where e.StudentID == id select e;

var days = dayList.ToList();
            if (days.Count > 0)
            {
                string dl = days.FirstOrDefault().listOfDays;
                string[] listofdays = dl.Split(',');
                ViewBag.classDay = listofdays.ToList();
            }